# ROSJava PubSub tutorial not publishing chatter topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed all the steps at http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html to attempt to get rosjava working.  I see no errors or significant warnings while following the steps to install and build the roscore.  However, when I attempt to launch the PubSub tutorial with this command: "roscore &
./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker &
./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Listener",
it does not seem to publish the 'chatter' topic.  Here is what I see in the terminal after I run the command: NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2937]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ubuntu:11311/

setting /run_id to 12c61b96-a542-11e1-9d85-000c29358351
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2954]

Furthermore, the directory that is referenced in the command (./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub) doesn't seem to exist.  However, when I build the nodes with "roscd rosjava_tutorial_services
../gradlew installApp", it says the build is successful.

I am running ros electric on Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks for the help
-Andrew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34711/rosjava-pubsub-tutorial-not-publishing-chatter-topic/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to look for the files in ./build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin

---

Originally posted by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) with karma: 155 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1